# How to get distinct rows from datatable with 10 million rows?

Tags: c#

I am reading Data from XML file and my xml file contain more then 10 million rows.
My XML file contain duplicate rows. I want to distinct rows from xml and insert it to database.

I have tried to use:

     `string myXMLfile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("ReadFilePath").ToString();`

```
 System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream(myXMLfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
 DataSet dsFileRecords = new DataSet();
 dsFileRecords.ReadXml(fsReadXml);

DataTable dtUniqRecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ID","Name");
```

// Insert rows to database from Datatable(dtUniqRecords)

But this method is takes lots of time. Any other methods to get distinct rows?

Comment: Using which database server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get distinct values from large table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685473/best-way-to-get-distinct-values-from-large-table)

Comment: "But this method is takes lots of time." - indicies may be key to solving this issue.

Comment: are you sure you have both ID and Name fields indexed. If not, do it and test it again...

Answer (score 3):

If the database is SQL based, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`. This will be much faster than anything you can do in c#.

EDIT: There really isn't anything you can do. Switching to an embedded DBMS, such as SQLite, is your best option if you can feasibly do it.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I'm aware of. If you want to do more complex analysis such as this on locally stored data, it might be worth switching to an embedded DBMS, such as SQLite. I believe there is a SQLite library for C#.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the rows read from the XML file into a temporary table in the database.  Use bulk copy if your database supports it.

Then use SELECT DISTINCT to transfer from the temporary table into your target table.

Answer (score 1):

With 10 million rows of data, you need to be using a database, not a text/xml file, to store your data. I am afraid there is not much you can do to speed up a process that depends on reading the entire file be read into memory at once and then scanned. Best to reconsider your architecture.

I would put all the rows into a database first, if only a temporary table, and then de-duplicate it there and insert into the final table; many more opportunities to improve performance with a real database.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL statement would be the fastest route. Something like:

```
USE database_name;
GO
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM table_name
```